# как обновлять страницу при определенной ширине экрана?

Tags: javascript

как обновлять страницу при определенной ширине экрана? допустим при ивенте resize, если  window.innerWidth === 600px. Один раз обновить страницу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let reloaded_once = sessionStorage.getItem("reloaded_once");
if (!reloaded_once) {

  window.addEventListener("resize", function _reloader() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 600) {
      window.location.reload();

      sessionStorage.setItem("reloaded_once", "true");
    }
  }, { once: true }); // Наверно не обязателен, добавлен на всякий случай:
 // Если быстро дергать - resizить, функция всё равно запустится единожды.

}
```

[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) хранит информацию, пока открыта вкладка браузера. Если закроют и перезайдут - функция будет запущена снова.

Comment: спасибо большое)